# Creating a "sticky" map with MapBox and Scrollama

Tags: scroll, mapbox-gl-js, sticky

I’m trying to create a “sticky” map using MapBox and Scrollama. Specifically, I’d like to be able to scroll down through the following sequence:

1. intro: narrative content
2. dynamic MapBox map with scrolling steps defined in a story element, fixed in place until all steps are completed
3. outro: more narrative content

My document is structured as follows:

```
<div id="intro"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="story"></div>
<div id="outro"></div>
```

And I style the MapBox map as follows:

```
#map {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            height:100vh;  
            width:100%;
        }
```

This works through sections 1 and 2 (intro and map/story), but once I’ve scrolled through all the steps in the map, I’m only able to scroll past the map by one line and I can't see any of the content in "outro." Any ideas for what I could do to enable scrolling out of the map to additional content?

I tried the following:

- setting `bottom: 0` , but that effectively positions the map as “relative” and separates the map from the scrollama content.
- using callbacks with .onStepExit to change the map from fixed to relative, but that was a nightmare with getting pixel positioning right across multiple platforms
- using an iFrame, but this depends on the user manually positioning the map in the center of the screen

Answer (score 0):

After nearly a week of thrashing I found the answer just minutes after posting this based on looking at [code from the SF Chronicle here](https://projects.sfchronicle.com/2019/kincade-fire-origin/). I swear these online forums have paranormal capabilities. As soon as I separated my  tags into  and  sections, everything worked as intended.

```
<main id="project-wrapper">
<div id="intro"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="story"></div>
</main>

<footer>
<div id="outro"></div>
</footer>
```